# How to use submit value in Controller switch case function?

Tags: laravel, switch-statement, submit

how can I get value data from submit button to validate the value in a switch case function? Here you can a part from my view.

```
{{Form::open(['route' => ['mgmtgroups_approvel', 'test' => $grouprequest->group_name]])}}
   Create User {{$grouprequest->username}} in Group {{$grouprequest->group_name}} ?
   {!! Form::submit('Yes',['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'submitbutton', 'value' => 'save'])!!}
   {!! Form::submit('No',['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'submitbutton', 'value' => 'nosave'])!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And this is my Controller function with the switch case function.

```
public function setGroupApprovel(Request $request){
switch($request->submitbutton) {
        case 'save': 
            $groups_create_subscription = new GroupSubscription();
            $groups_create_subscription->idgroups = $request->input('idgroup');
            $groups_create_subscription->subscriber = $request->input('iduser');
            $groups_create_subscription->save();
        break;
        case 'nosave': 
            $groups_request = new GroupRequest();
            $groups_request->iduser::find($request->iduser);
            $groups_request->request_active = 0;
            $groups_request->save;
        break;}
```

At the moment there is no use of the switch case function. Maybe the function is not able to read the submit value with 'save' and 'nosave'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `$request->get('submitbutton')` in your method :

for example :

```
public function setGroupApprovel(Request $request)
{
    switch ($request->get('submitbutton')) {
        case 'save':
            $groups_create_subscription = new GroupSubscription();
            $groups_create_subscription->idgroups = $request->input('idgroup');
            $groups_create_subscription->subscriber = $request->input('iduser');
            $groups_create_subscription->save();
            break;
        case 'nosave':

            $groups_request = new GroupRequest();
            $groups_request->iduser::find($request->iduser);
            $groups_request->request_active = 0;
            $groups_request->save;
            break;
    }
}
```

and i use :

```
<input id='submit' class="btn btn-default" type='submit' name = 'submitbutton' value = 'save'>
<input id='submit' class="btn btn-default" type='submit' name = 'submitbutton' value = 'nosave'>
```

instead of :

```
{!! Form::submit('Yes',['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'submitbutton', 'value' => 'save'])!!}
{!! Form::submit('No',['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'submitbutton', 'value' => 'nosave'])!!}
```

Comment: I get "Yes" and "No" back but I want to have the value "save" and "nosave".

Comment: I think your `blade` is wrong. you can use my input instead of your blade. I update my answer. please test.